# Invalid regexp group - проблема с регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения

У меня есть регулярное выражение

```
let re = /(?<=\[ATTACHMENT])[^[]+(?=\[\/ATTACHMENT])/g;
```

Это работает в хроме, но не работает в других браузерах.
Как мне правильно использовать это выражение?

Comment: `var re = /\[ATTACHMENT]([^[]+)\[\/ATTACHMENT]/g`

Comment: должно получиться значение между тегами [ATTACHMENT] и [/ATTACHMENT] в Вашем примере цепляется скобка ]. Что я должен исправить?

Comment: [Всё работает](https://regex101.com/r/nBL9zx/1),  как надо